# How to put variable value inside value of resource file

Tags: .net, resource-files

I have been working with resource files for a while now and I was wondering if there is some nifty way I don't know of yet to put variables inside a resource value.

A simple example:

> You have bought ***#amountOfBooksBought*** books.

My current way of working would be to declare two resource values (for 2 labels):

> BoughtBooksAmountPreTextLabel.Text : "You have bought "
>   BoughtBooksAmountPostTextLabel.Text : " books."

Inbetween the two labels with this text, there would be a label named BoughtBooksAmountValueLabel which contains the amount of books bought.

Is there a more elegant solution to this or is this just it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could put a formatted string in your resource file:

```
"You have bought {0} books."
```

Then use the formatted string with your value like this:

```
BoughtBooksAmountTextLabel.Text 
    = String.Format(yourResourceString, BoughtBooksAmountValueLabel)
```